# How to define a type that does not end with a given character

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript you can define template literal types like:

```
type Paragraph = `${string}\n`;

const paragraph: Paragraph = 'foo\n'; // ok
const word: Paragraph = 'foo'; // not ok
```

Is it possible to define the *opposite* type? That is, a string that *does not* end with a newline:

```
type NotParagraph = `???`;

const paragraph: NotParagraph = 'foo\n'; // not ok
const word: NotParagraph = 'foo'; // ok
```

Comment: Unless you do a function for that, I don't think it is possible

Comment: @Johan - Yeah, a function or you repeat the string literal (once as a type argument, once as the value).

Comment: I suspect I want a negated type: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196

Answer (score 0):

It's a hard one. I can only think of two ways to do it (but I'm still at the journeyman level in TypeScript). The more satisfying of the two is to use a do-nothing function to enforce the requirement:

```typescript
type NoTrailingNewline<T extends string> = T extends `${string}\n` ? never : T;

function noTrailingNewline<T extends string>(str: NoTrailingNewline<T>) {
    return str;
}

const paragraph = noTrailingNewline("foo\n"); // not ok
//                                  ^ Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
const word = noTrailingNewline("foo"); // ok
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gFQE4EMCWAbNA7A5jCAdy2wgB4EoIAPYCbAEwGcongkdcA+KAXiko06jFgAMAJAG82HPAF8AOtlFQA-FFIA3CEigAuAQG4AUMYBmAV2wBjYGjjYNiVJk4FiOcoNr1mrdpxcABQyBvDI6CT4RCReXACUUJLGUKlQSBDAFkiOMiZyptYObFBgKKi4qGAAFnxOEa547rFBAERmcHBKrfGGUAD0-U7AUHAA1sZF2CWEcEgMddjOkW4xnm0dcD19g6MTQA)

The other requires unsatisfying (and probably unacceptable) duplication:

```typescript
type NoTrailingNewline<T extends string> = T extends `${string}\n` ? never : T;

const paragraph: NoTrailingNewline<"foo\n"> = "foo\n"; // not ok
//    ^ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
const word: NoTrailingNewline<"foo"> = "foo"; // ok
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gFQE4EMCWAbNA7A5jCAdy2wgB4EoIAPYCbAEwGcongkdcA+KAXiko06jFgAMAJAG82HPAF8AOtlFQA-FFIA3CEigAuAQG4AUMYDGcbGyhgUqXKjAALA-GToS+IiXIAiAGZwcEq+PPwBQSGGUAD0MRpwwFBwANbmltaEcEgMroiomJwExDh+gXChfFARFdFxyWlAA)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could, I suspect that it wouldn't be super helpful. It's great to have precise types, but if types are *too* precise then it becomes hard to do anything with them. For instance string concatenation won't typecheck properly, or things like taking substring, replacing with a RegExp, etc. You would probably need a lot of `as`, so I think I would rather lean towards runtime checks.

A possible "cheating" solution is to define it as a nominal type (or at least Typescript's closest équivalent):

```
type NotParagraph = string & {__noTrailingNewLine: true};
```

It doesn't actually mean anything, it's just a type that looks like a string but for which you need `as` to create an instance of. So you can make a trim function for instance:

```
const trim = (str: string): NotParagraph => {
  return str.trim() as NotParagraph
}
```

and then if you make a function accepting a `NotParagraph` argument, it will only accepts what the `trim` function returns.